# Win32_SystemDriver to disable device drivers

Tags: c++, driver, wmi

Trying to find an answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181012/c-control-usb-drives-connected-to-my-system, I figured it out using the `SetupDiXxx Classes`. But the problem was that,once it is disabled/enabled, it was able to enable/disable the device from device manager. So any user can easily overcome the ban.

On further study, I saw that `Win32_SystemDriver` class of `WMI` has a `StopService` method that can be used to disable the driver for the device. But I am not sure on how to write the code for the same. Can anyone help me in coding this in `C++`. I am in `MSVS 2010`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access WMI classes in C++ with this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392109(v=vs.85).aspx
But that seems very hacky and not very easy. If you do this anyway, here is the shortest example I can find: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390421(v=vs.85).aspx . I've updated it to match what you're doing:

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
#include <comdef.h>

# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

void main()
{
    BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"StopService");
    BSTR ClassName = SysAllocString(L"WINMGMTS:\\\\.\\ROOT\\CIMV2\\ms_409:Win32_SystemDriver");

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;
    HRESULT hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        return;
    }

    hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,                          // COM negotiates service
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;
    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *)&pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }

    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        0,
        0,
        &pSvc
        );

    IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->GetObject(ClassName, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }

    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = NULL;
    hres = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0,
        &pInParamsDefinition, NULL);

    // Execute Method
    IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecMethod(ClassName, MethodName, 0, NULL, NULL, &pOutParams, NULL);

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

You would replace the classname to point to your driver. If you don't, it will fail with WBEM_E_INVALID_OBJECT_PATH. To find this, You need to enumerate your wmi objects so you can see/pick. This is definitely easiest in powershell, just open powershell and run `Get-WmiObject -class Win32_SystemDriver`. Although you should probably do all of this from powershell, come to think of it.

It sounds like you might instead want to consider learning how to leverage windows security policies for restricting which devices can be used:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530324.aspx  . You would start by launching gpedit and follow the directions until you've blocked device installation.

Comment: Can you giv a small example?

Comment: I am coding in VisaulStudio2010 using C++. I am not at al familiar with C#.

Comment: I didn't put any C#. The code is C++. Powershell is not C# either, it's just a shell built on .NET that comes preinstalled with Windows which is like 80 times easier and faster for querying this kind of junk.

Comment: Oh! I am sorry then.. Let me try it.. Thanks for your quick reply. :)

Comment: I am not able to make it to a working code. If u have a working example it will be much helpful :(

Comment: I copied over the rest of the example and made sure it builds. It doesn't work until you address the WBEM_E_INVALID_OBJECT_PATH error and fix the classname with your actual device.

Comment: Hey VoidStar, When I try stopService for CDROM, nothing is happening... I thought it would disable the CD.. :(

Comment: Check `hres` after making the call, if its 0 its a success, otherwise it will be some error, probably invalid object path.

Comment: I debugged line by line.. There is no error. hres returns S_OK always... The why is it not disabling the driver :(